# File upload over REST API - getting headers in the stream

Tags: file, codeigniter, http, rest, upload

I'm using the latest version of CodeIgniter and REST_Controller library for a REST functionality.

I'm trying to do a simple file upload to a server with Apache 2.2 and PHP 5.4 installed on it.

In order to get a content from the client, i've tried to use:

```
$file_content = $this->put();
//Or
$file_content = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

No matter which way I use, I always get something like this:

```
------WebKitFormBoundary3MTYXUNPMDmX8MXs
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="fileUpload"; filename="something.txt"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICXQIBAAKBgQC113DhhghzOiZHds2EOY7578Q1X141/kzpXodQZ4sCq+dOs3/O
iZS/j2y7ScE+4aRzQrPw/fPCsotwcCARfR0mhbKtUB8pE1n2pTcXJxqRGQPIVk6g
ZjsVhuCk9l880Zx8M4A2ebOR1i0SgLazpThlh3BNLPbwDIuXYE+9Qp94uQIDAQAB
AoGBALF61kz3wfWdEtF7bfmZKChf0XR6YXx3eN/piE580RvJZpjU73BJrioNtYVS
5k8WcqiguPoFE067bwdOGK6ZG8HgzfgZvs8hVN153fPoidmkPPvViwD7bNDJIG/5
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
------WebKitFormBoundary3MTYXUNPMDmX8MXs--
```

This, of course, is not good since there are some HTTP headers inside with a boundary.

So the question is - is there a way not to get these tags or how to clean them out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the File Uploading class for this:

- http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html
- https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Upload.php#L346

Don't forget you need to configure the Upload object, the uploaded file cannot be read from the temp dir, it needs to be moved to a local dir with read/write permissions.